# Regex for finding names after number

Tags: python, regex

I have string which contains names:

```
"1. Sachin Deshpande 2. K. Chandra Shekar 3. B. Rupesh 1. Prabhakar Rao 2. Venkata Chary 3. B. Gangadhar"
```

I need list of names from above string. I have tried `(?:[0-9][).])+(\D*)` this regex but it gives false results as well. Any help would be appreciated.

above regex also matches with `raj sharma 4) mirror ship`

I am looking for regex which checks the sequence for number

Output should look like this :

```
["Sachin Deshpande","K. Chandra Shekar","B. Rupesh","Prabhakar Rao",...]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With:

```
\d+\.\s+(\D+)(?:\s+|$)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Wr4sSb/1)

Python demo:

```
>>> import re 
>>> s="1. Sachin Deshpande 2. K. Chandra Shekar 3. B. Rupesh 1. Prabhakar Rao 2. Venkata Chary 3. B. Gangadhar"
>>> re.findall(r'\d+\.\s+(\D+)(?:\s+|$)', s)
['Sachin Deshpande', 'K. Chandra Shekar', 'B. Rupesh', 'Prabhakar Rao', 'Venkata Chary', 'B. Gangadhar']
```

If you have

```
"1) Sachin Deshpande 2) K. Chandra Shekar 3) B. Rupesh 1) Prabhakar Rao 2) Venkata Chary 3) B. Gangadhar"
```

You can use:

```
\d+[.)]\s+(\D+)(?:\s+|$)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZUg4FO/1)

Comment: Thanks for help. Tho it does not match with "1) Sachin Deshpande 2) K. Chandra Shekar 3) B. Rupesh 1) Prabhakar Rao 2) Venkata Chary 3) B. Gangadhar"

Comment: That is an easy fix: `\d+[.)]\s+(\D+)(?:\s+|$)` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZUg4FO/1)

Comment: Even simpler for any single character following the digits -> r'\d+.\s+(\D+)(?:\s+|$)'

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
x="1. Sachin Deshpande 2. K. Chandra Shekar 3. B. Rupesh 1. Prabhakar Rao 2. Venkata Chary 3. B. Gangadhar"
res=(re.split('\d+\.\s', x)[1:-1])
print(res) #has spaces at end of names
res=[i.rstrip() for i in res]
print(res) #removes trailing spaces
```

Answer (score 0):

`/(?<=[0-9]\)|\. )+(\D*)/gm`
There will be a space after it, but I tried my best :P

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the capture group, and if you also want to able to match digits in between:

```
\d[).]\s+(\S.*?)\s*(?=\d+[).]|$)
```

**Explanation**

- `\d[).]` Match a digit and either `)` or `.`
- `\s+` Match 1+ whitespace chars
- `(\S.*?)` capture group 1, Match at least a single non whitespace char, and then any char af few as possible
- `\s*` Match optional whitespace chars
- `(?=\d+[).]|$)` Positive lookahead, assert the starting pattern to the right or the end of the string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Jh9Ast/1)